# Java getText() from JTextField returns empty string while there is text in it

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a login form but when I try to get the username text and password text from the textfields it returns as an empty string.

```
public class Login extends JPanel {

private JLabel lblUsername;
private JLabel lblPassword;
private JButton btnLogin;
private JTextField txtUsername;
private JPasswordField txtPassword;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    setLayout(null);

    lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:");
    lblUsername.setSize(80,20);
    lblUsername.setLocation(80,40);

    lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
    lblPassword.setSize(50,20);
    lblPassword.setLocation(80,80);

    txtUsername = new JTextField();
    txtUsername.setSize(150,20);
    txtUsername.setLocation(160,40);

    txtPassword = new JPasswordField();
    txtPassword.setSize(150,20);
    txtPassword.setLocation(160,80);

    btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.setSize(150,30);
    btnLogin.setLocation(120,120);

    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {   
        System.out.println("Username " + txtUsername.getText() + " - Password: " + txtPassword.getText());
        sqlFunctions database = new sqlFunctions();

        if (database.checkAdminLogin(txtUsername.getText(), txtPassword.getText()) == true) {
            System.out.println("Login success");
            Frame.hideLogin();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login is niet gelukt, probeer opnieuw.");
        }

      }
    });

    add(lblUsername);
    add(lblPassword);
    add(txtUsername);
    add(txtPassword);
    add(btnLogin);



}

}
```

I've had this issue with this project before. When I tried to use a buttonhandler for multiple buttons and work with if cases and e.getSource() it would never recognize which button was clicked.

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: In the first place, why are you creating labels in paintComponent... You should create this at initialisation of the component and let the layout manage that for you. Secondly - please include your button and text edit creation code - we cannot see what exactly you are doing without it.

Comment: @Mr Rgo This is from the example they gave me at school. I have added my full class as I'm not sure what you mean with text edit creation code.

Comment: Everything is done in the paintComponent, you should leave that alone unless you want to override the way your Login panel is actually drawn on screen. Move all of that code to the constructor - `Login() { super(); ... }`. See if it works then. And don't use `setLayout(null)` rather use `setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);`

Comment: So, every time you paint the component, you create items on the panel? How do you know *which* txtUsername has text in it -- there could be a dozen of them floating around. This code is just broken; no one should be creating components here, no one should be placing them at absolute locations, you need to figure out how to build a Swing form before you worry about getting input from one.

Comment: don't add an action listener within paintComponent() either... When learning Swing, don't put ANYTHING in paintComponent, you should not need to.

Comment: Thanks guys. Moved all of my code to the constructor Login() and it works now.